# Make form node invisible at the first glance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn from Stack Overflow's "add a comment" link with code of three sections:

1. `footnote-list`
2. `footnote-form`
3. `add-form-link`

```
<div class="col-md-12 footnotes">
    <div class="footnote-list">
        <ul class="footnote-list">
          ....
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footnote-form"> make it invisible
      <form>
         ...
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="add-form-link">
        <a href="{% url 'article:footnote_add'%}" class="add-article-footnote" id="{{ article.id }}">add a footnote</a>
    </div>
</div><!-- footnotes -->
```

I intend to make `"footnote-form"` invisible at first glance, later to emerge when `"add-form-link"` is clicked.

The nodes could be shown and hidden using `$().hide()` `$().show()`after the page successfully loads.

How can I hide a node at the very beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide elements on load... CSS is prefered.

Then to show it, you need a click handler. The `e.preventDefault()` prevents the normal behavior of a link.

```js
$(".add-form-link a").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".footnote-form").show();
});
```

```css
.footnote-form{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 footnotes">
  <div class="footnote-list">
    <ul class="footnote-list">
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footnote-form"> make it invisible
    <form>
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="add-form-link">
    <a href="{% url 'article:footnote_add'%}" class="add-article-footnote" id="{{ article.id }}">add a footnote</a>
  </div>
</div><!-- footnotes -->
```